# Is CreateFile exception safe?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++-2015

I am using CreateFile() to open and read a file.  If an exception is thrown will the file be closed or do I need to catch it and close the file myself.  If the latter is true, what is the best way to catch and close the file.
Thanks!

Comment: `CreateFile` is a C function therefore it never throws exceptions. But yes, you are responsible for closing file under all circumstances.

Comment: A file opened with `CreateFile()` will not be magically closed when an exception is thrown.   If you want to ensure that, either close the file in an exception handler or use RAII techniques (treating the file handle as a resource) to ensure the file is closed.      Files will be typically be closed when the program terminates - including as a result of an unhandled exception - but any pending operations on files opened directly with `CreateFile()` may  not be completed (e.g. buffered output may not be flushed to the file) before closing.

Comment: Do you really need `CreateFile`? There are many wrapper classes available that take care of closing the file automatically in their destructor. MFC has `CFile`, standard C++ has `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`.

Comment: Should I use     catch (CFileException* pfileexcept) {
        pfileexcept->Delete();
    }  
to handle closing of the file.

Comment: @zett42 no, but this is old legacy code 1 million lines long.

Comment: In this case consider to wrap the handle with class [`CAtlFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/catlfile-class), which takes ownership of the handle and automatically calls `CloseHandle` in its destructor (in contrast to `CFile` which doesn't take ownership). E. g. `CAtlFile myFile(hFile);`

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the significance of the tags [tag:c] and [tag:mfc]? Those are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @IInspectable Not necessarily. This is an interop question between `CreateFile` (a C-style function) and MFC (a C++-based framework).

Comment: @RaymondChen: Maybe that is the case. But the OP claims, that they are using `CreateFile` *"to open **and read** a file"*. Leaving me puzzled, just what they are doing, or whether MFC is involved at all.

Comment: @IInspectable  I'm used to QT/C++ this is the first time I have used MFC and I thought CreateFile() was part of MFC.  I did not understand that it is a c-style function.

Comment: `CreateFile` is not part of MFC. It's a Windows API call, the foundation of any Windows framework.

Answer (score 1):

The file won't be closed. If you want to make sure it is closed, you can wrap it in [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) with custom deleter, like this:

```
struct HandleDeleter
{
    void operator ()(HANDLE hObject) { CloseHandle(hObject); }
};

using SafeHandle = std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, HandleDeleter>; // for convenience

void someFunction()
{
    // automatically closed at the end of parent scope:
    SafeHandle hFile(CreateFile(...));

    throw std::runtime_error("the file will be closed now");
}
```